Please help me identify this picture of Devi, who is she?

Her skins looks slightly green? I can't recognise any particular iconography sadly.
The text does not seem to help at all and I wonder if it has been added later.

This is clearly a digitally edited photo of Lakshmi, incorporating elements of Kali.

She is most likely Kamalātmikā (Tāntrika characterisation of the goddess of prosperity, Lakṣmī); one of the Daśa Mahāvidyā-s, albeit represented with green colour like the Mahāvidyā Mātaṅgī. In proper iconography she has golden complexion.

She has a beautiful golden complexion. She is seated on a lotus.In her four hands, she holds two lotuses and makes the signs/mudras of granting boons (varada) and giving assurance (abhaya). She wears a resplendent crown and a silken dress.


